# Getting a list of yum updates via ansible fails

Tags: linux, ansible, yum

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  user: username

  tasks:
  - name: List Available Patches (Non-Kernel)
    yum:
     list: updates
     update_cache: true
     exclude: kernel*
     register: yumoutput

  - debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname}} {{ yumoutput.results }}"
```

MSG:

```
Unsupported parameters for (yum) module: register Supported parameters 
include: allow_downgrade, bugfix, conf_file, disable_gpg_check, 
disable_plugin, disablerepo, enable_plugin, enablerepo, exclude, 
install_repoquery, installroot, list, name, security, skip_broken, state, 
update_cache, update_only, validate_certs

to retry, use:
```

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.6.5
```

Same issue on `2.7.5` version.

Comment: Please format the `yml` content as a code so that we can see the actual formatting of your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an indention error. `register` has to be on the same column as `yum`.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  user: username

  tasks:
  - name: List Available Patches (Non-Kernel)
    yum:
      list: updates
      update_cache: true
      exclude: kernel*
    register: yumoutput

  - debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname}} {{ yumoutput.results }}"
```